# Extract loaded debug symbols into .pdb

Tags: debugging, symbols, ida, pdb-files

I'm currently reversing a new application and encountered a strange behaviour: Browsing the running application with 'Cheat Engine' reveals the function names retrieved by the loaded symbols.
An example address: 'xxxx.lua_getinfo+A8EE'

The applications I've reversed so far never had symbols loaded and the address looked something like this: 'XXX.exe+834AF0' (means it has no symbols loaded)

Opening this application in 'IDA Pro Advanced' doesn't reveal any symbols but only generical named functions.

Does somebody know how to extract these symbol names and their addresses into a file like .pdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lua_getinfo` is probably just one of the DLL's exports, and Cheat Engine uses the closest one to show you this expression. It does not mean that the address in question actually belongs to the `lua_getinfo` function.

Comment: No, this was only an example. All function-calls are properly named.

Comment: Well, without having the file it's hard to say how exactly Cheat Engine found discovered the symbols.

Comment: I speak about the Game 'RIFT' which is available to download at http://www.riftgame.com/

Comment: I think @IgorSkochinsky is correct because an offset of A8EE is over 42K.